# Feed Keras model from dataset with pandas

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset in CSV file and read it through `pandas` with `data = pd.read_csv(filename)`. Then **Text** and **Score** columns are loaded.

I am not sure which is the suitable way to feed Text/Score as x_train/y_train for keras neural network model. I do:

```
max_fatures = 2000
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_fatures, split=' ')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data['Text'].values)
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data['Text'].values)
X = pad_sequences(X)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = nb_epochs, batch_size = nb_batch_size, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

But I get a Memory error in `X = pad_sequences(X)`.

How should I feed the model?

Comment: Look into generators, and Keras model's `fit_generator` method.